# How to solve : EnrichR website not responding?

Tags: r, package

I have faced with working EnrichR, is there any solution to solve it?

```
install.packages("enrichR")

library(enrichR)
dbs <- listEnrichrDbs()

`EnrichR website not responding`

dbs <- c("GO_Molecular_Function_2015", "GO_Cellular_Component_2015", "GO_Biological_Process_2015" , "ChEA_2016" ,"KEGG_2016")
enriched <- enrichr(c("Runx1", "Gfi1", "Gfi1b", "Spi1", "Gata1", "Kdr"), dbs)

`EnrichR website not responding`
```

or is there any quick way (not getting one by one) to get whole tables of enrichment from Enrichr?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What package version are you using? The error is listed in `.onLoad` which according to the source code should show that the website is done. The site appears to be live though.

Comment: it is the Version: 2.0

Answer (score 2):

The original @MaayanLab #Enrichr API and server are working fine. #Enrichr was recently slightly modified and that broke that R package. That R package is a wrapper developed independently by @W_Jawaid who recently fixed this issue. Please view this thread: https://github.com/wjawaid/enrichR/issues/21. Version 2.0 and earlier had a bug - version 2.1 available now from Github is working. It should test the website when you load the package. CRAN is on holiday for August, so 2.1 is not there yet.

## TL;DR

Version 2.1 available now on GitHub should fix it.

```
install.packages("devtools") 
devtools::install_github("wjawaid/enrichR")
```